# Bottom of the page footer positioning issue

Tags: position, footer

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make my footer stick to the bottom of the screen, even when the page is smaller than the screen.

www.test-domain.sk

I'm guessing it's something to do with the container length, but I'm honestly completely unsure.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This concept is something known as a sticky footer. The Mozilla Developer Network has a page [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_cookbook/Sticky_footers) illustrating a few ways to accomplish it. In the example of your www.test-domain.sk page, I believe you can add the following css to make your footer stick to the bottom of the viewport (screen).

```
html {min-height:100%)
body {100vh}
div#page {min-height:100vh; display:grid; grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, natt, but I don't think it's a footer issue. It's probably a container issue and I'm unsure what to change to make it work :)

Comment: You're correct...it always involves a wrapping container element with a min-height of 100%. If you set the following css properties, I think you'll get what you're looking for. On you html element, `min-height:100%`. On your body element: `min-height: 100vh`. On your div#page element, `min-height:100vh; display:grid; grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto`.

Comment: Thanks a million, natt. It's this part of the code I was missing and didn't know how to write and where:
div#page element, min-height:100vh; display:grid; grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto

Comment: You're welcome! I updated the answer to include the information in the comment. If you found it helpful, you could mark it accepted so that anyone who finds your question will more easily see how it was answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for something like this, but if not, be more specific. As in post the code you already have.

```css
footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: `#colophon {
      color: #fff;
      position: relative; }
    #colophon .site-info {
        background-color: #212120;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 30px 0;
        line-height: 1;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }`

If you look at the code and the main page, you'll see the issue. Basically, if the page is longer than the screen, I seem to have done it right. But when there's a page shorter than the screen it's viewed on, the page ends early. 
Might this not be a footer issue, but a site length issue?

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying now. I usually wrap everything in a container that has no other purpose than to control the elements on the screen. Example: <body> <div id="container"></div></body> and all other elements are inside those tags. In the css I set the container height to auto. I've also seen other set viewheight to 99 or 100 and a handful of other ways. I also set the footer the way I showed above. Here's another way: https://medium.com/@zerox/keep-that-damn-footer-at-the-bottom-c7a921cb9551